# Set accessibility badge on a tabbarItem

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, uitabbaritem

I have a tabbar application. If there is a badge on a certain tab VoiceOver pronounces `N items`. I'd like to make it pronounce `N messages`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,
it seems that UITabBarViewController.tabbar is handling accessibility differently than other views.
So my solution was placing another uiview above the badge as a subview of  [tabbar superview] and adding accessibility to this view:

At viewDidLoad:

```
self.badgeAccessibilityView = [[UIView alloc] init];
//use tabBarView.frame to calculate
self.badgeAccessibilityView.frame = frameAccordingToBadgeLocation;
self.badgeAccessibilityView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.badgeAccessibilityView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
[self.tabBarView.superview addSubview:self.badgeAccessibilityView];
```

On badge value change:

```
self.badgeAccessibilityView.accessibilityLabel = 
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Notifications", badgeValue];
```